# pipe as arguments

Tags: linux, command-line, arguments

I'm trying to use the output of a command as arguments:

The command:
`/home/alexandre/dropbox.py exclude add ls | grep -v photos`

I have to add a list of files, for example:

`/home/alexandre/dropbox.py exclude add a.txt b.txt c.txt`

`ls | grep -v photos` will give me a list of all files except the folder `photos`.

But if I use my command, the command adds exclusion for the file `ls` (which does not exist, I want to run the command `ls`).

Anybody know how to do that?

Comment: You want something like `dropbox.py exclude add $(ls | grep -v photos)` (in bash and some other new shells).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is to execute the command in a subshell, like:

```
/home/alexandre/dropbox.py exclude add $(ls | grep -v photos)
```

Comment: exactly what I need, thanks! I thought that it was very easy!

Answer (score 0):

Use `find`:

`find . -path ./photos -prune -o -type f -iname '*.txt' -exec /home/alexandre/dropbox.py exclude add {} +`

Comment: it must work also, but why is it better that my solution?

Comment: the `find` version works even if there are spaces or newlines or other problematic characters in the filenames.

Comment: without `find` you can take steps to make it work with any character *except* newline in the filename...but newline is a valid character in filenames so you can't guarantee that there won't be one.

Comment: Obligatory reference: [Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).